# How to stop Pandas to_csv from reducing datetime precision

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I'm trying to fix up some poorly formatted CSV datasets with timestamps of the format `%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.%f` e.g. `2020-09-14_19:29:43.377000` so I run the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.%f')
df.to_csv('file_fixed.csv', index = False)
```

But then I notice that the output CSV has `to_csv` or Pandas in general has decided to trim the date to less precision e.g. `2020-09-14 19:29:43.377`. If I don't want to reduce such precision to 3 decimal places how do I stop this?

Comment: Maybe try with `df.to_csv('file_fixed.csv', index=False, date_format='%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.%f')`

Comment: @PApostol Yep that does the trick, thank you!

Comment: note that you don't even need an extra line to parse the dates; you can set the `parse_dates` keyword to parse upon import, see [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).